# How many integers between $100$ and $500$ are divisibly by both $6$ and $12$, but not by $9$?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

The numbers divisible by both $6$ and $12$ and just the numbers divisible by $12$, so:

$12 \times 9 = 108$

$12 \times 41 = 492$

$\frac {492-108}{12} = 32 + 1 = 33$ numbers divisible by $12$, and in turn div. by $6$

$\frac {495-108}{9}+1 = 44$ numbers divisible by $9$

So there are $500-44 = 466$ numbers not divisible by $9$

Here is where I am stuck.  Any help?

Comment: **HINT** 492-180 divided by 12 does not equal 33

Comment: I know. ((492-108)/12) + 1 does.

Comment: You could similarly count numbers divisible by 36.

Comment: Then I would be counting numbers divisible by 9.

Comment: You would be counting numbers divisible by both 12 and 9. From this and the 33 you got, you should figure out the answer.

Comment: There are 12 numbers divisible by 36.  If I subtract this from 33, I get 21. Is this it? If so, how?

Answer (score 1):

if you observe $6*n$ .you will see that for your condition to be true.

$n$ should be even and at the same time $n$ should not be divisible by $6.$

therefore  the numbers start from $6*20$ to $6*82$.

now find the number of even numbers from $20$ to $32$ and subtract the number of multiples of $6$ from it.
$$32-10=22$$

Answer (score 1):

The number of integers divisible by $12$ between $[100,500]$  is $$N_1=\left\lfloor\frac{500}{12}\right\rfloor-\left\lfloor\frac{100-1}{12}\right\rfloor$$

As lcm$(12,9)=18,$  among these $N_1$ numbers, the number of integers that are also divisible by $9$ between $[100,500]$ will be $$N_2=\left\lfloor\frac{500}{18}\right\rfloor-\left\lfloor\frac{100-1}{18}\right\rfloor$$

So, the required number of integers will be $N_1-N_2$

Comment: @Oiclid, how about this?